# CakePHP Custom Search in Multi-Level Model Relations

Tags: model, pagination, cakephp-2.0

I am hoping someone can shed some light on this issue. I have read tons of stackoverflow docs, cake docs, the works, and I cannot seem to solve this. I have a model relationship as follows:

- Horse belongsTo Vendor
- Horse belongsTo Lot
- Vendor hasMany Horse
- Lot hasMany Sale
- Lot hasMany Withdrawal

Then, I am listing all the Lots and displaying a table with Horse, Vendor, Lot number etc etc. This is working fine, in fact using the Paginator::Sort method I can even sort be Vendor.name ASC or DESC, which tells me that the associations are correct.

I cannot - however - seem to manipulate the search results based on a match against ANY field belonging to Vendor. For example, if in my paginate settings I do something like this:

```
'conditions' => array('Vendor.name' => 'Simon')...
```

I get an SQL error that column Vendor.name does not exist, yet if I remove this conditions constraint and I then assess the SQL, it most certainly is there.

It should also be said that I am using the unbindModel() and bindModel() methods to create on the fly hasOne relationships for optimal MySQL overhead, and this has not resulted in the problem at hand, as it was there before.

Here is the first row I get back when I var_dump() the paginated results:

```
'Vendor' => 
    array
      'id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'name' => string 'ALDORA STUD' (length=11)
      'surname' => string '' (length=0)
      'address' => string '' (length=0)
      'tel' => string '' (length=0)
      'fax' => string '' (length=0)
      'email' => string '' (length=0)
      'url' => string '' (length=0)
      'comments' => string '' (length=0)
      'created' => string '0000-00-00 00:00:00' (length=19)
      'modified' => string '0000-00-00 00:00:00' (length=19)
      'modified_by' => string '0' (length=1)
  'Withdrawal' => 
    array
      'id' => null
  'Sale' => 
    array
      'id' => null
      'catalogue_id' => null
      'lot_id' => null
      'purchaser' => null
      'amount' => null
      'notes' => null
      'date' => null
```

I have omitted many lines, but you can clearly see that Vendor is being sent back as a hasOne relationship to Lot, the controller I am working in.

If it is of help, I am using this code to unbind and re-bind models:

```
        $this->Lot->unbindModel(array(
            'hasOne' => array('Horse'),
            'hasMany' => array('Withdrawal', 'Update', 'Sale'),
            'belongsTo' => array('Catalogue')
        ));

        $this->Lot->Horse->unbindModel(array(
            'belongsTo' => array('Vendor', 'Lot')
        ));

        $this->Lot->Horse->Vendor->unbindModel(array(
            'hasMany' => array('Horse')
        ));

        $this->Lot->bindModel(array(
            'hasOne' => array(
                'Catalogue' => array(
                    'foreignKey' => false,
                    'conditions' => array('Catalogue.id = Lot.catalogue_id')
                ),
                'Horse' => array(
                    'foreignKey' => false,
                    'conditions' => array('Horse.id = Lot.horse_id')
                ),
                'Vendor' => array(
                    'foreignKey' => false,
                    'conditions' => array('Vendor.id = Horse.vendor_id'),
                ),
                'Withdrawal' => array(
                    'foreignKey' => false,
                    'conditions' => array('Withdrawal.lot_id = Lot.id'),
                    'fields' => array('id')
                ),
                'Sale' => array(
                    'foreignKey' => false,
                    'conditions' => array('Sale.lot_id = Lot.id')
                )
            )
        ));

        $this->Lot->contain(array('Sale', 'Catalogue', 'Withdrawal', 'Horse', 'Vendor'));
```

My paginator calls then look like like follows:

```
$this->paginate = array(
                    'contain' => array('Sale', 'Catalogue', 'Withdrawal', 'Horse', 'Vendor'),
                    'conditions' => array('Vendor.name' => 'Somerset Stud'),
                    'maxLimit' => ($this->params['ext'] == 'csv' ? 1000 : 25),
                    'limit' => ($this->params['ext'] == 'csv' ? 1000 : 25),
                );
```

And that's when I get the error that the column Vendor.name does not exist.
If anyone can share some tips and ideas I'd be eternally grateful.

Kind regards,
Simon

Comment: Simon, do you need the `$this->Lot->contain(array('Sale', 'Catalogue', 'Withdrawal', 'Horse', 'Vendor'));` after you do the binding?

Comment: @Moz Morris - Usually I would not need this, especially when I can use the contain property in the Paginate class. However I have set Recursive to -1 in my AppModel class, so I need to re-declare all relationships, even when creating them on the fly as above.

Comment: currently you are in which controller

Comment: I am currently working in the LotsController

Answer (score 0):

From what i can see you are not in vendors controller/model but some other model.

```
$this->paginate = array(
                  'contain' => array('Sale', 'Catalogue', 'Withdrawal','Horse',
                  'Vendor'  => array('conditions' => array('Vendor.name'=>'Stu'),
                                     'order'      => array(),
                                     'fields'     => array())
                );
```

The above code should work . There may be syntax errors but i hope you are getting what i mean

Here is a example from book http://book.cakephp.org/view/1323/Containable

```
$this->Post->find('all', array('contain' => array(
    'Comment' => array(
        'conditions' => array('Comment.author =' => "Daniel"),
        'order' => 'Comment.created DESC'
    )
)));
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however this produces a very odd result. I used the above syntax, filtered by Vendor.name = 'HIGHLAND STUD' and the result was that all 349 results were still rendered, but they ALL had the same vendor value of HIGLAND STUD which is incorrect.

So to summarize, all the above did was give every record in the results the same vendor value.

Any ideas why? Appreciate your efforts.

Comment: It's just bizarre that using the following works:

`conditions => array('Horse.name' => 'someValue')...`

Whereas Vendor.name does not, they are both controllers outside of the controller I am working in, and both have been altered to have a hasOne relationship to Lot